# MSVC compile variations of same source code and then link them all together

Tags: visual-studio

Using the MSVC compiler I can do this from the command prompt

```
cl /c /Foout1 dispatch_example.cpp
cl /c /arch:AVX /Foout2 dispatch_example.cpp
cl instrset_detect.cpp out1.obj out2.obj
```

How to I make a Visual Studio project file do this?  I mean so that from the command prompt I can do

```
msbuild foo.vcxproj
```

and it builds everything or so that I can build the project from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [online instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)  what you typed in should work.

```
C:\Users\Mikhail\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\openMPProducerConsumer\openMPProducerConsumer>notepad fun.out

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18034]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 5/13/2013 6:34:08 PM.
Project "C:\Users\Mikhail\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\openMPProducerConsumer\openMPProducerConsumer\openMPProducerConsumer.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Debug\openMPProducerConsumer.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
Link:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  openMPProducerConsumer.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Mikhail\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\openMPProducerConsumer\openMPProducerConsumer\x64\Debug\openMPProducerConsumer.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Debug\openMPProducerConsumer.unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Debug\openMPProducerConsumer.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Mikhail\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\openMPProducerConsumer\openMPProducerConsumer\openMPProducerConsumer.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.36
```